# tab deliminator does not create separate columns for the fields separated by tab; content of different columns are mixed

Tags: python-3.x

I have used the following code to separate between three fields using tab; I want see all "IDs" in one column, all titles in one column, etc...

```
each_file.write(b['_source']['dataset']['Identifier']+"\t"+"title: " + "\t" + title + "\t"+"description: " + "\t" + description+ "\n")
```

The attached file shows the output:
[image]

I want to know what 's wrong with the code that I see some parts of the description field in the identifier field.

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I suggest you put a sample of data in the file you process in your question. 
In term of file output, if it supposed to be a CSV file, you need to specify \t as the delimiter when you open the file in excel. The problem with this delimiter is the high possibility it has that's been used in the data itself. I think you'd better use a really unique delimiter instead of Tab character, something like $=$ to separate each column when you generate the file, and use the same when you open it in excel. 
Another point to mention: if you only want to display data to the end user, it's Ok to convert it to CSV or Excel, but remember that these formats are not portable enough. So it'll be hard to process them later too.